# How do I make the Multipler(number) for calculating ISBN to decrease after each loop statement

Tags: java

Good day house. 
This is an iterative approach to solving:

An ISBN-10(International Standard Book Number) consists of 10 digits:
 If the checksum is 10, the last digit is denoted as X according to the ISBN-10 convention.

Write a program that prompts the user to enter the first 9 digits and displays the 10-digit ISBN (including leading zeros). I wrote the  code  with the  aim of  making   the  number to decrease after  each loop statement,  but my  present code  used only number 9 all  through .  I would  therefore  appreciate  how  to make  it  achieve the  desired  result. Thank  you.

```
   import java.util.Scanner;
   public class Isbn {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      //create  scanner
      Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
      // prompt  users  to enter 
      System.out.println("Enter 9  digit ISBN:");
         int isbn = s.nextInt();
         int sum=0;
         int number=9;
   //create loop
        while (1<=number){
        int lastdigit = isbn%10;
        int  digitcal = lastdigit*number;
          sum += digitcal;
          number--;
   System.out.println(sum);
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: `isbn` doesn't change inside your loop, so neither does `isbn % 10`.

Comment: you are not making changes to isbn. and also your code is not doing what you wants

Comment: any test case or example ?? can you explain so it will be good to understand your problem.

Comment: @Alan . Thank  you. For the case study, users are expected to input 9digit isbn number e.g. 987654321.  The  multiplier( the  position that correlates to  each  digit )  will  be  used  in multiplying  each isbn digit and  the result will be  summed up .  For the  example: (9*1) + ( 8*2)+(7*3)+…….. The   sum  will  be  divided  by  11 to  determine  the  10th  isbn digit

Comment: @Prashant. Thank you. For the case study, users are expected to input 9digit isbn number e.g. 987654321. The multiplier( the position that correlates to each digit ) will be used in multiplying each isbn digit and the result will be summed up . For the example: (9*1) + ( 8*2)+(7*3)+…….. The sum will be divided by 11 to determine the 10th isbn digit

Comment: @pumpin26 You should edit that into your question, not add it as a comment. In any case it doesn't address my point: if `isbn` never changes, your program can't work. How can you fix that?